# What is this 3 metre tall shrub whose bottom comes from lots of thick stems?

Tags: identification

I'm not sure if the berries change colour or not. Right now they are the size of peas and look like little watermelons. As you can see, the leaves are weird and look like sea urchins.

Can anyone tell me what plant this is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an Asparagus, maybe [*Asparagus densiflorus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus_densiflorus).

Comment: can you provide more detail and references about why you think it's asparagus?

Comment: Well, they looks the same ! (by the way, sorry if I do english errors, I'm french).

Comment: thankyou trevorannedenise you put me on the right track and i googled photos and i think i found it. 'Asparagus retrofractus' so thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

This is an asparagus fern. They grow little white flowers which turn into the berries in your picture. I prefer to grow them in hanging baskets instead of letting them droop on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a type of asparagus. This is a Ming Fern (Asparagus Macowanii or A. retrofractus, same plant). The growth pattern of the Ming is very distinctive and it is the only variety I know of that has the brown colored stems. Most other Asparagus species are all of a color. They are poisonous, have small thorns and since they are not a true fern they can thrive in pretty dry conditions, and like to at least dry out between waterings. They prefer full sun, but will adapt to all but the lowest light conditions, though this will slow their growth proportionally. They are a great easy care, unique, elegant, beautiful plant, and can sometimes be hard to find. The berries (seeds) stay green. Don't eat them.

Comment: Hi Zeddikus. Wow, you've only been here a short time and have given so much help to the community! Thanks for your knowledge, and willingness to jump in and share it. We're so glad you found us, and hope you stick around!